# how to create LLL of char arrays

Tags: c++

it seems like every guide is how to create LLL with ints, but I'm having trouble using char pointers. when i run this code, it segfaults immediately

here's my code thus far

```
struct node    
{
  char * data;
  node * next;   
};

void build(node * head);//create list    
void manipulate(node * & head);//manipulate list    
void display(node * head);//display all    
void delete_list(node * head);//delete all nodes in linked list    
bool again();//asks user if they'd like to continue

int main()
{
  node * head = NULL;
  //create list from user1 input
  while(again)
    build(head);
  //displays list
  display(head);
  //manipulate list as user2 reads through it
  manipulate(head);

  return 0;
}

void build(node * head)
{
  head->next = new node;
  char * data = new char;
  cout << "where to visit? ";
  cin.get(head->data,strlen(data)+1,'\n');
  head = head->next;
}
```

Comment: and what does the debugger say

Comment: WTH's a **LLL**?? Explain please ...

Comment: You are evaluating `again` in your `while` loop instead of calling it. It will always evaluate to `true`.

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd assume LLL is Linear Linked List, right?

Comment: yes, linear linked list. sorry, it's the term my instructor used and I assumed it was in common usage

Comment: interesting that the compiler allowed while(again). an implicit conversion from function to bool

Answer (score 2):

I assume this code:

```
while(again)
    build(head);
```

Was meant to be (calling `again` instead of comparing it to zero):

```
while(again())
    build(head);
```

Either way, the first time through the loop `head` is NULL. But `build` goes ahead and uses it anyway:

```
head->next = new node;
```

Here, using `next` will produce a segment fault because `head` is NULL. You are accessing an invalid location in memory.