# Creating a linear linked list from a .txt file

Tags: c++

I would like to read in a .txt file and create a linear linked list from it.

Here's an example of the .txt file.

```
word1; word2; num3; word4;
word11; word22; num33; word44;
```

What I have so far is

```
    ifstream file_in;

    file_in.open("word.txt");
    file_in.get(word, SIZE, ';');    file_in.ignore(SIZE, ';');
    while(!file_in.eof()) 
    {
            file_in.get(desc, SIZE, ';');    file_in.ignore(SIZE, ';');
    }
```

Comment: There is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20506471/how-to-create-lll-of-char-arrays

Comment: c or c++? not both. While(!file_in.eof) doesnt do what you think, dont use it

Comment: What is an LLL?  Linear Linked List?

Comment: Yes LLL is Linear Linked List

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal code for homework reads more like this:

```
std::ifstream myfile("filename.txt");
std::string fullline;
while(std::getline(myfile, fullline)) {
   //got a line, now split into words
   std::istringstream line(fullline);
   std::string word;
   while(std::getline(line,word,';') {
       //do something with the next word
       //note that it probably has leading spaces since it's semicolon delimited.
   }
   //end of line
}
//end of file
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Mooing Duck, I'm really bad with external files.

Answer (score 1):

come at it from the other direction. Write a set of functions for creating and populating linked lists. And test with hard coded values. Once they are working nicely wire them up in a program that reads input from a file. The linked lists are the hard part

ie

```
List *make_list()
{
//yr code goes here
}

void add_to_list(List *list, char * word)
{
// ditto
}
```

etc

then

```
int main()
{
   List *list = make_list();
   add_to_list(list, "word1");
   add_to_list(list, "word2");
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try at it from that direction, thanks a lot, honestly. I didn't think of that.

Comment: i see u say c++ - in that case use std::string not char *

Comment: hey pm100, i am suppose to do this without using string.

Comment: Yeah I don't know why he does that, but anyways, thank you for your help!